# how to put pagination to a list of non persistent domain - grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, pagination

Hi I have a list of an entity which is non persistent domain because it has a combined properties of two entities. I usually use the

```
def c = Case.createCriteria()       
def caseList = c.list(  [max: criteria.max, offset: criteria.offset]
```

but this does not work in my list because the getting of data is diff. I had to get data from table A first then combine it with data from Table B. then I loop each to create a new Entity. look code below.

```
if(criteria.caseNoteType==0)
        {
            caseNoteList = searchClaimNotesByClaimNote(criteria)
            for (CaseNote n: caseNoteList)
            {
                note = new ClaimNote()
                note.dateAssigned = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(n.cmCaseIdCmCase.assignedDate) //n.cmCaseIdCmCase.assignedDate
                note.claimOwner = n.cmCaseIdCmCase.employeeIdEmployee.formatName()
                note.caseNoteType = "Claim Notes"
                note.caseNoteTitle = n.caseNoteTitle
                note.noteOwner = n.employeeIdEmployee.formatName()
                note.claimNo = n.cmCaseIdCmCase.id
                note.clientName= n.cmCaseIdCmCase.clientIdClient.formatLastNameFirstNameMiddleInit()
                note.caseNoteText = n.caseNoteText
                note.id = n.id

                claimNotesList.add(note)
            }
            cmcaseList = searchClaimNotesByCaseComments(criteria)
            for (CmCase n: cmcaseList)
            {
                note = new ClaimNote()
                note.dateAssigned = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(n.assignedDate) // n.assignedDate
                note.claimOwner = n.employeeIdEmployee.formatName()
                note.caseNoteType = "Case Comments"
                note.caseNoteTitle = n.caseTitle
                note.noteOwner = n.employeeIdEmployee.formatName()
                note.claimNo = n.id
                note.clientName= n.clientIdClient.formatLastNameFirstNameMiddleInit()
                note.caseNoteText = n.caseComment
                note.id = n.id
                claimNotesList.add(note)

            }



        }

        def cmCaseListFinal = null
        def cmCaseCount = claimNotesList.size()
        if ('caseNoteType' == criteria.sort  ) {
            cmCaseListFinal = claimNotesList.sort { a, b ->
                if ( 'asc' == criteria.order )  a?.caseNoteType <=> b?.caseNoteType
                else   b?.caseNoteType <=> a?.caseNoteType
            }
        } else if ('dateAssigned' == criteria.sort  ) {
            cmCaseListFinal = claimNotesList.sort { a, b ->
                if ( 'asc' == criteria.order )  a?.dateAssigned <=> b?.dateAssigned
                else   b?.clientIdClient?.dateAssigned <=> a?.dateAssigned
            }
        } else {
            cmCaseListFinal = claimNotesList
        }

        return  cmCaseListFinal



    }
```

here is the code for searching with criteria. thesame goes with other entity being combined.

```
def searchClaimNotesByCaseComments(ClaimNoteSearchCriteria criteria)
{

    log.info ( criteria )
    def c =  CmCase.createCriteria()

    def cmCaseList = c.list([max: criteria.max, offset: criteria.offset] )
    {

        createAlias("clientIdClient", "client")
        createAlias("employeeIdEmployee", "employee")
        createAlias("internalOrgIdInternalOrg", "InternalOrg")

        if ( criteria.clientSsnSearch  != null && criteria.clientSsnSearch.trim() != '' ) {
            criteria.clientSsnSearch = criteria.clientSsnSearch.trim()
            like('client.clientSsnSearch', criteria.clientSsnSearch)
        }
        //C#
        if (  criteria.clientVaFileNbrSearch  != null && criteria.clientVaFileNbrSearch.trim() != '' ) {
            criteria.clientVaFileNbrSearch = criteria.clientVaFileNbrSearch.trim()

            eq ( 'client.clientVaFileNbrSearch',  criteria.clientVaFileNbrSearch.toString()   )

        }
        // Service Number
        if (  criteria.clientMilitaryServiceNbr   != null && criteria.clientMilitaryServiceNbr.trim() != '' ) {
            criteria.clientMilitaryServiceNbr = criteria.clientMilitaryServiceNbr.trim()

            like ( 'client.clientMilitaryServiceNbr', ( criteria.clientMilitaryServiceNbr  as String).trim() + '%'  )

        }
        // Last Name
        if ( criteria.clientLastName != null && criteria.clientLastName != '' ) {

            like ( 'client.clientLastName', (criteria.clientLastName as String).trim() + '%'  )

        }
        // FirstName
        if (  criteria.clientFirstName  != null && criteria.clientFirstName  != ''  ) {

            like ( 'client.clientFirstName',   (criteria.clientFirstName  as String).trim() + '%'  )

        }
        // employeeIdEmployee
        if ( criteria.employeeIdEmployee != null ) {

            eq ( 'employee.id', criteria.employeeIdEmployee )

        }
        //poaStatus
        if ( criteria.intOrgLegalName != null && criteria.intOrgLegalName != '' ) {

            like ( 'InternalOrg.intOrgLegalName',  (criteria.intOrgLegalName  as String).trim() + '%'  )

        }
        if ( criteria.caseNoteText != null  && criteria.caseNoteText != '' ) {

            like( 'caseComment',  (criteria.caseNoteText  as String).trim() + '%'  )
        }


    }

    return cmCaseList

}
```

here is my code for the paging

```
<div class="gadgetLong">
  <div> <span class="gadgetName"><g:message code="claimSearch.searchResult.label" default="Search Results" /></span><span class="gadgetNumber">${ claimNoteList.size() }</span></div>
   <span class="gadgetNumber">${ claimNoteList.size() }</span>
  <span class="gadgetNumber"> <g:paginate next="Next" prev="Back"
        maxsteps="0" action="sortclaimSearch" 
          total="${ claimNoteList.size() }" /></span>
  </div>
  <div>
```

I want to add pagination to the final List without using create criteria because it is already past the search.  is there a work around on this? or what am I doing wong? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a method to get a sublist and render in view the sublist as the list and the list.size() as the total... maybe something like this in a service (whatever you want):

```
def getSubList(List objectList, Map params) {
    //verify params
    try {
        params.max = params.max.toInteger()
        params.offset = params.offset.toInteger()
    } catch (Exception exceptionInstance) {
        params.max = 10
        params.offset = 0
    }
    //Verify pagination params... if not you add them
    if (params.max <= 0) {
        params.max = 10
    }
    //Get total size of the list
    def objectInstanceTotal = objectList.size()
    //verify offset.
    if (params.offset < 0 || params.offset > objectInstanceTotal) {
        params.offset = 0
    }
    //Verify the pagination border (don't excess from array border).
    Integer bordeInteger = params.max + params.offset
    if (bordeInteger > objectInstanceTotal) {
        bordeInteger = objectInstanceTotal
    }

    //Extract the sublist based on the pagination.
    def objectSubList = objectList.subList(params.offset, bordeInteger)

    return objectSubList
}
```

And in the controller:

```
def list = {

   def list = //Define your list

   def subList = service.getSubList(list, params)

   [list: subList, listInstanceTotal: list.size()]
}
```

In the view, you paginate as always calling de list action

Hope this helps ;)