# Grails <g:paginate> for map in action (index) ,without Domain class

Tags: grails, pagination

I'm having a problem in `<g:pagination>`. I didn't use domain classes, I just used a one action (index) which contains map named `${finalmap}`. I send it to gsp. `<g:each>` works with it. But `<g:pagination>` doesn't work for me. I send `[params:params,finalmap:finalmap]` for offset and max variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243151/how-to-put-pagination-to-a-list-of-non-persistent-domain-grails

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap the contents in your finalMap in a map with the structure

```
[
list: <your data in list form for the page>,
totalCount: <total entries for the entire list>
]
```